# Sort with case-sensitivity (lowercase before uppercase) in macOS in the Terminal

Tags: bash, sort

I am trying to use the answer in [GNU Sort by case-sensitive](https://superuser.com/questions/178171/gnu-sort-by-case-sensitive?newreg=991875d16d8f46e09bf5caf792d0ba63) to sort a file in my Mac OS.

My `file.txt` looks like this:

```
"Best"
"A"
"BEST"
```

In the second answer to the mentioned question, it says that one can do:

```
echo -e "d\nD\nc\nb\nB\na" | sort --ignore-case file.txt
```

and the output should be:

```
"A"
"Best"
"BEST"
```

However, when I do it in my computer, I get:

```
"A"
"BEST"
"Best"
```

It does not matter if I use the `--ignore-case` or not, the output is the same.

Maybe `LC_COLLATE=C` can not be set in Mac OS?

Does someone know how to use `sort` and have lowercase < uppercase in Mac OS?

**EDIT**

@jaume recommended installing `coreutils` and using the GNU sort. I tried `brew install coreutils` and then `gsort -f file.txt` but still had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort order is defined in your `locale`.

```
locale            
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

When LC_COLLATE is defined as LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" on macOS, LC_COLLATE uses the C or POSIX definiton. The default behavior of `sort` is to sort in ascii order where uppercase has precedence over lowercase.

On Linux, when  LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" the LC_COLLATE definiton is non-standard. The default behavior of `sort` is to ignore-case and lowercase has precedence over uppercase.

To mimic Linux default `sort` behavior on macOS, You can use `tr` to "translate" lowercase letters to uppercase and uppercase to lowercase, sort with the `ignore-case` option (`-f`), then change the case back again.

```
tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z' <file.txt | sort -f | tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z'
```

EXAMPLE:

```
cat file.txt
"cat"
"Best"
"A"
"BEST"
"Castro"
"alfred"
"a"
"CAT"

tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z' <file.txt | sort -f | tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z'
"a"
"A"
"alfred"
"Best"
"BEST"
"Castro"
"cat"
"CAT"
```

Comment: Hi @fd0, `sort -m "$@" file.txt | tr 'a-zA-Z' 'A-Za-z' | sort file.txt` works. The last command has to be deleted or all lowercase-uppercase letters are swapped. Would you mind deleting that part? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: All I understand is that the output of one command is fed into another, but I have to honest and say I was not sure where I should put the filename. I tried different combinations and the one in my first comment worked. Happy to learn where one has to set the file name in your original solution. Thanks.